# Asymptotic distribution of zero-drift Geometric Brownian Motion as $t \to \infty$

Tags: stochastic-processes, asymptotics, stochastic-calculus, finance

If we fix the drift at $\mu = 0$, then my geometric brownian motion will have stationary mean, but it seems that the variance will grow without bound. What does the limiting distribution look like for different volatilities? Is there a "tipping" point where its limiting distribution behavior changes?

Comment: the limit is not measurable so it doesn't look like anything I am afraid. If you put a non zero trend the story is different  as it converges almost surely to $0$ or $+\infty$. You can also notice that the result changes when you move to another probability measure by the means of Girsanov theorem for example. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge Thanks...the case where $\mid \mu \mid > 0$ was pretty clear. Are we in a situation where a driftless GBM process is a lot like the Cauchy sample mean...never settling down? Surely, if we simulated enough GBMs over a very long time horizon, we'd get results all over the map, I'm guessing.

Comment: This comes from the fact that BM is recurrent (so $liminf_{t\to \infty} B_t=-\infty$ and $limsup_{t\to \infty} B_t=+\infty$ almost surely so this doesn't give much hope regarding measurabillity. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge OK, so its not a measurable function...but does it even converge to $a$ function?

Comment: Obviously it is not does the function f(x)=sin(x) converges when x goes to infinity it is the same here Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be clear, I'm assuming that you mean the process $dX = \sigma X dW$ where $W$ is Brownian motion.  According to the theorem 12 from [these lecture notes](http://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Geometric.html) at Brown University, driftless geometric Brownian motion converges to zero with probability 1.  They sketch a proof in terms of the law of the iterated logarithm.

You can also specialize the results from the answers to [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24825/asymptotic-behavior-property-of-geometric-brownian-motion-proof) at Quant Stack Exchange.

Loosely related is [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/16133/24120) to a different question, which makes an interesting big-picture point.  At any finite time, $E_0(X_t) = X_0$, so its surprising that the long-run limit is zero.  The answer locates this weird result in a failure of a probabilistic property known as "uniform integrability".

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the references!